# Implement Zxing barcode reader with TextureView

Tags: android, view, crop, zxing

I'm trying to put Camera Preview of Zbar scanner into TextureView but Android Studio keep returning rendering error.

"Exception raised during rendering: android.view.TextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup"

How can fix it.

```
 <TextureView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_read_barcode">

<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:zxing_use_texture_view = "true"
    app:zxing_preview_scaling_strategy="centerCrop">
</com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView>


</TextureView>
```

activity code here

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.ResultPoint;
import com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeCallback;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeResult;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MoveIssueReadBarcode extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mButtonHome, mButtonBack, mButtonRead;
    ListView listView;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    List<Items> row;
    TextView setUser, setBase;
    TextureView cameraView;
    TextView barcodeInfo;
    DecoratedBarcodeView barcodeView;
    private BeepManager beepManager;
    private String lastText;


    private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            if(result.getText() == null || result.getText().equals(lastText)) {
                // Prevent duplicate scans
                return;
            }

            lastText = result.getText();
            barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());
            beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();

        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {

        }


    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_move_issue_read_barcode);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar3 );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );


        //Barcode reading
        cameraView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeInfo);

        barcodeView = (DecoratedBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);

        beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        barcodeView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        barcodeView.pause();
    }

    public void pause(View view) {
        barcodeView.pause();
    }

    public void resume(View view) {
        barcodeView.resume();
    }

    public void triggerScan(View view) {
        barcodeView.decodeSingle(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return barcodeView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void doInit(){


    }


}
```

[I want to put preview in black area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MOEy.png)

Comment: post activity code where u initialize texture view

Comment: i added my activity code